# VS 2015 linking fltlib.lib

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

Iam trying to write a console application in 64 bit.I have linked the required library in the

```
Properties->Linker->Addidional Input->fltLib.lib
```

It wouldnt work so I added Addidional Directory in

```
Propertied->Linker->General->Addidtional Directory->C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.14393.0\um\x64
```

It still gives unresolved symbol FilterConnectCommunicationPort

I also tried copying the fltlib.lib file in my local directory and then

```
#pragma comment(lib, "fltLib.lib")
```

Still it complains about unresolved external externals.

After that I tried adding header directory in

```
C/C++->General->Additional Include Directory->C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.14393.0\um
```

Still it gives errors saying unresolved external symbols.

I have also tried including the headers in an extern "C" block.
I'm really confused as to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If `fltLib.lib` is located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.14393.0\um\x64` why don't you give the complete path in `Properties->Linker->Addidional Input`

Comment: It is not complaining about not being able to find the .lib file, so what you've been doing was not useful.  Post the actual linker error messages you get.

Comment: Please, note: 1. You have to include header files for the _compiler_ (i.e. function prototypes are defined before you call the functions). 2. Include paths may be defined (e.g. as compiler option) to allow relative paths in the `#include` directives (in the source code). 3. Additionally, you have to add the (corresponding) library (or libraries) for the _linker_ so that it can resolve calls of the resp. functions. I was not sure whether this is clear for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio you have to add the folder, which you have already done by setting the property Linker > General > Additional Library Directories. You also need to set the name of the file you will be linking against. This is done by putting the "fltlib.lib" in the Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies field.

If you have multiple lib files in one directory it might be easier to use the Linker > Command Line option: [PATH TO LIB FOLDER]*.lib". Keep in mind that statically linking (against lib files) increases the size of your build files, so unnecessary linking against everything should be avoided